# Why do I get errors trying to debug with RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine

I work on JetBrains RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1 with Ruby193. I used to debug all the time until rubymine popped up an update for ruby-debug and I clicked yes. Ever since that update I tried to reinstall previous versions and I get this error:

```
Failed to Install Gems. Following gems were not installed: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\RubyMine 5.4.2\rb\gems\ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre12.gem: 
Error installing ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre12.gem: 
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError) 
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre12 for inspection. 
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre12/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
```

Obviously I do have the Devkit installed properly because it did work until now (tried reinstalling ruby and devkit again but no luck).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look in

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre12/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out

posting the contents of this file may be useful if you don't see the answer in there yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Both gems; ruby-debug and debugger; mess up debugging through RubyMine. Also, I had to manually install a version of linecache (0.5.13) to get the IDE debugging to work. Here is my gem list.

```
actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
activeadmin (0.6.0)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activerecord-import (0.4.1)
activerecord-postgresql-adapter (0.0.1)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
arbre (1.0.1)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.10)
backbone-relational-rails (0.8.5, 0.7.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bourbon (3.1.8)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
childprocess (0.3.9)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
columnize (0.3.6)
commander (4.1.3)
curb (0.8.4)
curl-multi (0.2)
daemon_controller (1.1.4)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3)
devise (2.2.4)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
eco (1.0.0)
eco-source (1.1.0.rc.1)
ejs (1.1.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.9.0)
foreigner (1.4.2)
formtastic (2.2.1)
has_scope (0.5.1)
highline (1.6.19)
hike (1.2.3)
httpclient (2.3.3)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
inherited_resources (1.4.0)
io-console (0.3)
jasmine (1.3.2)
jasmine-core (1.3.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.4)
json (1.8.0)
kaminari (0.14.1)
linecache19 (0.5.13)
mail (2.5.4)
meta_search (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.23)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
minitest (4.7.5, 2.5.1)
modernizr (2.6.2)
modernizr-rails (2.6.2.3)
multi_json (1.7.7)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-ssh (2.6.8)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
open4 (1.3.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paperclip (3.4.2)
passenger (4.0.5)
pg (0.15.1)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pr_geohash (1.0.0)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
rails-backbone (0.9.10)
rails-footnotes (3.7.9)
railties (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.9.5)
responders (0.9.3)
rhc (1.10.7)
rsolr (1.0.9)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.2)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.26)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre12)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta17)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (2.0.3)
RubyInline (3.12.2)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)
spork (0.9.2)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
sunspot (2.0.0)
sunspot_rails (2.0.0)
sunspot_solr (2.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.0)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.1)
underscore-rails (1.4.4)
warden (1.2.1)
websocket (1.0.7)
ZenTest (4.9.2)
zurb-foundation (4.2.2)
```